# Operand type mismatch when using "jmp *%esp"

Tags: c, assembly, stack-pointer

I have this snippet in my code

```
void jmp_esp()
{
    __asm__("jmp *%esp");
}
```

when compiling with gcc

```
gcc aslr.c -o aslr -ggdb -fno-stack-protector -z execstack
```

i get this error.

```
aslr.c: Assembler messages:
aslr.c:6: Error: operand type mismatch for `jmp'
```

Why this line is failing to compile although the assembly instruction is valid ?

I've read about DEP (Data Execution Prevention). could it be that this feature is creating this compilation error ? if so, how to disable it ?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but this is not a valid use of inline asm since you have no control over the value of `%esp` when the inline asm block is entered. In particular it is **not** necessarily the value of the stack pointer at function entry. If you need to do this you need an asm source file or file-scope asm statement defining the function entry point rather  than a C function.

Comment: @R..: I suspect the OP wants the 2-byte sequence to appear somewhere in their code for playing with a ret2reg attack, not for calling this function normally.  Of course putting it at the global scope with a label on the actual instruction would make it easier to find (no need to search the machine code, just use `nm` and look for the `jmpesp:` label you added).

Comment: @R.. as Peter Cordes said, i was just playing around with ASLR bypassing and wanted the jmp *%esp to appear in the assembly code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instruction `jmp *%esp` is available only in 16 and 32 bit modes. In 64 bit mode, `jmp r/m32` cannot be encoded.  Depending on what your intent is, there are two ways to fix your code:

- if your intent is to write a 32 bit x86 program, compile and link with `-m32` to make the compiler emit 32 bit code.
- if your intent is to write a 64 bit x86 program, change the instruction to `jmp *%rsp` to jump to the address contained in the `rsp` register instead.

Note that this is independent of DEP.  DEP prevents the execution of memory regions not specifically marked as executable.  This happens at runtime, not at compile time.